# WCF server events

Tags: c#, wcf

If I have a WCF server app that need to inform WCF client that some action should be done (for example "redraw user interface") what would be the best method to achieve this? Is there any "event" mechanism i can use to inform a client that it should perform some action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do callbacks - but not for all bindings. IMHO it's better to either let the client poll or let the client itself decide if it should do anything.
If this is for games or whatever I would reconsider using WCF in the first place (performance).

Comment: Yes, it's for game :\ Travian-like game, it's almost done, it just needs server "backbone" for storing data. I also have a big database so, i will have to use Linq for sake of simplicity, even if i know it has poor performance...

Comment: is this silverlight/web or do you have native apps? Because as I said callback contract won't work with (Ws)Http or such. I have to admint that I don't know "Travian" but if it's a turn-based strategy game then polling is fine IMHO

Comment: Well it's not a browser game. It's multiplayer game like "Travian", or "Ogame" or "Lord of Ultima" - it's not turn based. It has client part (C# user interface, but i would like to try to create Java client too) and a server part for calculations, data storage and so. I would try callbacks because when server stores some data in database, it should let the client know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use callbacks. A beginner guide here: http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx